# the way of writing constructor, deconstructor and copy constructor for matrix class

Tags: c++, constructor, copy-constructor

I am trying to create a constructor, destructor, and copy constructor for  a matrix class, and I am not so sure if I am doing it well.

In particular, I am not sure about 2 things:

1. Is the destructor suppose to free memory also for the memory that is allocated in the copy-constructor?
2. As to the line `Mat[i][j]=other[i][j]` (see in the code below), I wonder if I should write `Mat[i][j]=other.Mat[i][j]` instead?

```
class Matrix
{
private:
    int rows;
    int cols;
    int **Mat;

public:
    Matrix (const int &rows,const int &cols);
    Matrix (const Matrix &other);
    ~Matrix ();
};

Matrix::Matrix(const int &n_rows,const int &n_cols) //constructor of class Matrix
{
    rows=n_rows; 
    cols=n_cols;
    Mat=new int* [cols];

    for(int i =0;i<rows;i++)
       Mat[i]=new int[cols];

    for(int i=0;i<rows;i++)
      for(int j=0;j<cols;j++)
        Mat[i][j]=0;            
}

Matrix::~Matrix () //destructor
{
    for(int i =0;i<rows;i++)
        delete Mat[i];

    delete[] Mat;
}

Matrix::Matrix(const Matrix &other)  //copy constructor
{
    cols=other.cols;
    rows=other.rows;
    Mat=new int* [other.rows];

    for(int i =0;i<other.rows;i++)
       Mat[i]=new int[other.cols];

    for(int i=0;i<other.rows;i++)
      for(int j=0;j<other.cols;j++)
            Mat[i][j]=other[i][j];
}
```

Comment: You will also want the copy assignment operator. See the [rule of 3/5/0](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

Comment: Use one std::vector.

Comment: I think Francois was going in this direction but I could be wrong. To do a deep copy you need to overload the assignment = operator. Without a deep copy you will have a shallow copy, which the destructor will deallocate all memory associated with that instance.

Comment: 1) Yes. 2) `other.Mat[i][i]` to summarize the answers.

Comment: @AnthonyVoelker François was definitely going in that direction. The Rule of Three states that if you need a custom copy constructor, assignment operator or destructor, you almost certainly need all three.

Comment: user4581301...thought so, I am a but rusty with C++. Been doing a lot of C lately which should explain the rust.

Comment: but do you think I should fix what I written thus far (about the the deconstructor , for instance) ?

Comment: If you want an example of a Matrix class, read "The C++ programming language" by Bjarne Stroustrup. Ah, and I think you forget about the move constructor.

Answer (score 0):

A **constructor** is a class operation that initializes an object instance of a specific class.

The object creation involves several operations such as:

1. Allocating memory to store the structure for the new object
2. Initializing the object's attributes properly.

A **copy constructor** is a special case of constructor, that takes an instance of the same class as an input parameter. - It is still a constructor, performing the same operations mentioned above.

A **destructor** is a class operation which is responsible for finalizing an object when it is not to be used anymore.

An object can be constructed using any constructor it defines, either ordinary or copy constructor. When you delete that object, any memory allocated by your class should be deallocated in the destructor.

Hope this helps.

As for your code related question; when invoking a copy constructor, you pass an existing object instance of the class. Since you don't have any operator overloading implemented, you access the object's property like you said in #2.

I am not sure if this answers your questions fully, but I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

1) I think deconstructor erases only object that belongs to, because copy-constructed objects have their own destructor.

2) Yes, `Mat[i][j] = other.Mat[i][j]` is right, but if you want your program to be bit faster, try using pointers (it isn't easy at first time, I know, but when you get used to it isn't that hard ^^)

Comment: I still dont understand...Does destructor suppose to free the memory allocated also in the copy constructor?

Comment: Copy constructor is just an overloaded "normal" constructor, so it creates an object the same way as "normal" constructor.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes. Anything the object still has allocated should be freed in the destructor.  It doesn't matter which constructor allocated it.
2. Yes, you need to use `Mat[i][j]=other.Mat[i][j]`, especially since you haven't defined any `operator[]` for your class.

You also need to add a copy assignment operator, per the ["Rule of Three"](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three), which basically states:

> If a class requires a user-defined destructor, a user-defined copy constructor, or a user-defined copy assignment operator, it almost certainly requires all three.

Try this:

```
class Matrix
{
private:
    int rows;
    int cols;
    int **Mat;

public:
    Matrix (int n_rows, int n_cols);
    Matrix (const Matrix &other);
    ~Matrix ();

    Matrix& operator=(const Matrix &rhs);
    // alternatively:
    // Matrix& operator=(Matrix rhs);
};

Matrix::Matrix(int n_rows, int n_cols)
{
    rows = n _rows; 
    cols = n_cols;

    Mat = new int*[rows];
    for(int i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
    {
       Mat[i] = new int[cols];
       for(int j = 0; i < cols; ++j)
           Mat[i][j] = 0;
    }
}

Matrix::Matrix(const Matrix &other)
{
    rows = other.rows;
    cols = other.cols;

    Mat = new int*[rows];    
    for(int i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
    {
        Mat[i] = new int[cols];
        for(int j = 0; j < cols; ++j)
            Mat[i][j] = other.Mat[i][j];
    }
}

Matrix::~Matrix()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
        delete Mat[i];
    delete[] Mat;
}

Matrix& Matrix::operator=(const Matrix &rhs)
{
    if (&rhs != this)
    {
        Matrix temp(rhs);
        std::swap(Mat, temp.Mat);
        std::swap(rows, temp.rows);
        std::swap(cols, temp.cols);
    }

    return *this;
}

// alternatively:
/*
Matrix& Matrix::operator=(Matrix rhs)
{
    std::swap(Mat, rhs.Mat);
    std::swap(rows, rhs.rows);
    std::swap(cols, rhs.cols);
    return *this;
}
*/
```

A better solution is to not use `new[]`/`delete[]` directly at all.  Use `std::vector` instead, and let it handle everything for you, thus allowing your class to follow the "Rule of Zero":

> Classes that have custom destructors, copy/move constructors or copy/move assignment operators should deal exclusively with ownership (which follows from the [Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.com/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)). Other classes should not have custom destructors, copy/move constructors or copy/move assignment operators.

```
class Matrix
{
private:
    std::vector<std:vector<int> > Mat;

public:
    Matrix (int n_rows, int n_cols);
};

Matrix::Matrix(int n_rows, int n_cols)
{
    Mat.resize(n_rows);
    for(int i = 0; i < n_rows; ++i)
       Mat[i].resize(n_cols, 0);

    /* alternatively:
    Mat.resize(n_rows, std::vector<int>(n_cols, 0));
    */
}
```